# Do some math and display it in base adapter (listview)

Tags: android, listview

I have few values in which I  display in listview using base adapter. 
Now I want to get 2 values and for example multiply them and then display them in listview. It should be done for each item in listview.

so this is my code I done for now but I get stuck.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_logs, parent, false);
        }
        TextView logMass;
        Logs log = logsList.get(position);

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDiameter)).setText(log.getDiameter());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLength)).setText(log.getLength());


        double log_length;
        double log_diameter;
        double length;
        double diameter;
        log_length = Integer.parseInt(log.getLength().toString());
        log_diameter = Integer.parseInt(log.getDiameter().toString());
        length = log_length / 100;
        diameter = log_diameter * log_diameter;

        logMass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAmount);
        Log.d("Result", String.valueOf(length * diameter));
        logMass.setText(String.valueOf((length * diameter)));
        return convertView;
}
```

So i would like what is the proper way to multiply these values and set them to TextView.

And also would like to hear some advice for sum all results form all items. for example if i have 13 items in listview I would like to get all results from each item and sum it to one result.

Comment: your code snippet is incorrect.
'result' is string and double?
also you assign 'result' to your textview before and then do math and assign the answer into 'result'

Comment: I just edited code with fixes. error is now when i setting the result to textview. in this line             logMass.setText(String.valueof(value1 * value2));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure it out. Just need to set it to textView like this
`((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAmount)).setText(final_result);`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RubyDigger, some interesting things are going on in your code here.
At what point are you getting stuck?

Are you stuck specifically at the point of "trying to get 2 values"? Are these values entered as arguments from the user or something else?

Comment: Yes, these two variables (getLength() and getDiameter()) are from database (user enters them). So i get length and diameter into the variable 1 and variable2. I do some math into the value1 and value 2.  
I tried to display that result into textview but it throws me an error in line       `logMass.setText(String.valueof(value1 * value2));`.

Comment: can you tell us the exception?

Comment: just guessing, maybe `value1` or `value2` are 0? so NaN?

Comment: it is NullPointerException. value1 and value2 are not empty it display the values in Log and it works. Don't know why it doesn't accept it in textview.

Comment: Ok well everything after "logMass" is good.... I should say the "setText(String.valueOf(value1 * value2)); is fine... The problem is with "logMass"....it sounds like maybe R.id.textAmount might be the problem. Which layout is textAmount found in???....Is the value simply not appearing in the TextView or is the App crashing?

Comment: then `logMass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAmount);` is null. are you sure R.id.textAmount is ok?

Comment: App is crashing. I think R.id.textAmount is good. I'll just update code in question so you can see in which layout it is.

Comment: Ok so now that you've changed the code, is this line: "logMass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAmount);"  throwing the error, or this line: "logMass.setText(String.valueOf((length * diameter)));"